# Scala lambda function not resolved when declares the type of parameter?

Tags: scala, lambda, compiler-construction

when defining method in Scala, I found this

```
def method1: Int => Int = (j: Int) => j  // works
def method2: Int => Int = j => j  // works
def method3: Int => Int = j: Int => j  // error
def method4: Int => Int = {j: Int => j}  // works
```

Can anyone explain why method3 does not work? Is there any ambiguity in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible explanation is indeed that this restriction avoids ambiguity: `x: A => B` could be understood as an anonymous function that takes a parameter `x` of type `A` and returns the object `B`. Or it could be understood as "casting" a variable `x` to the type `A => B`. It is very rare that both of these would be valid programs, but not impossible. Consider:

```
class Foo(val n: Int)
val Foo = new Foo(0)
val j: Int => Foo = new Foo(_)

def method1: Int => Foo = (j: Int) => Foo
def method2: Int => Foo = j: Int => Foo

println(method1(1).n)
println(method2(1).n)
```

This actually compiles and prints:

```
0
1
```

Comment: That looks like the correct answer I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All of these variants are covered by [Anonymous Functions section of the specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#anonymous-functions). The relevant part is

> In the case of a single untyped formal parameter, `(x) => e`
>    can be abbreviated to
>   `x => e`. If an anonymous function `(x : T) => e` 
>    with a single typed parameter appears as the result expression of a block, it can be abbreviated to
>   `x: T => e`.

In `method3`, the function isn't the result expression of a block; in `method4` it is.

EDIT: oops, presumably you meant why the limitation is there. I'll leave this answer for now as stating what the limitation is exactly, and remove it if anyone gives a better answer.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what "the result expression of a block" means? Does it mean the “{}"？

Comment: @RossKeth Yes. One kind of expression in Scala is a block expression: 0, 1, or more expressions surrounded by `{` `}`. The result expression of a block is its last expression.